# im trying to get the combination (probability) of 2 numbers

Tags: c, combinations

```
unsigned long long int first( int b , int c){
int h=b;
//int k;
for(int k=b-1;k>c;k--){

    b=b*k;
    }
int comb=b/factorial(h-c);
return comb;
   }
```

this function return right answers for some cases and wrong answer to others. can anyone help me please is there anything wrong with this function?!

Comment: For what cases is it correct? For what cases is it incorrect? Please provide a [Minimal, Completed, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: for 17 and 9 the answer is correct.

Comment: for 17 and 6 the answer is wrong

Comment: Can you show the code for `factorial`?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the right formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `int comb` is `int` you are returning int!

It does not matter that you are suppose to return `unsigned long long int first`. The result of the devision is rounded to `int` value, precision is lost.

Comment: the answers are int in my test cases, so the is no rounding

Comment: @HannaNassar comb is `int`. It can only fit `int`  b,k is `int` and you are returning `long long`. If you expect result as `long long` do not do operation on `ints`.